# android alarm manager run background service every 15 minute

Tags: android

hey there i am trying to run android background service every 15 minutes using alarm manager but i am unable to do so i don't what mistake and i can't figure out whats wrong in my code its not working

```
try {
        //Create a new PendingIntent and add it to the AlarmManager
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RingAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            12345, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am =
            (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
                3000,pendingIntent);
        
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          
      }
```

RingAlaram.class

```
public class RingAlarm extends Service { 
      public void onCreate() {  
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hi there", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
}
```

and last my manifest

```
   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.alarmmanagerexample.AlarmManagerExample"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <service 
            android:name=".RingAlarm"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>
```

Comment: Set flag to PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Comment: @AC-OpenSource still its not working

Comment: @AC-OpenSource i did but no i result i tried on startcommand flag upadate and even made changes in  manifest  but did'nt work

Comment: I just noticed that you are using getActivity instead of getService.

Comment: @AC-OpenSource please post the full code and i will accept your answer

Comment: Done posting the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76870/discussion-between-ac-opensource-and-ankita-bansal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `getService` instead of `getActivity` and pass the application context (`getApplicationContext`) instead of activity context (`this`).

```
    //Create a new PendingIntent and add it to the AlarmManager
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RingAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 12345, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 3000, pendingIntent);
```

RingAlaram.class

```
public class RingAlarm extends Service { 
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hi there", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Also set flag to PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT instead of CANCEL
And set service declaration on manifest to `<packagename>.RingAlarm` might be `com.example.alarmmanagerexample.RingAlarm` in your case (I don't know your project structure).

Comment: That't the right answer, but Service code won't compile this way. You have to return either Service.START_NOT_STICKY or START_STICKY or START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY from onStartCommand() method. 
In this case Service.START_NOT_STICKY would make sense

Answer (score 1):

Change getActivity to getService

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, RingAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,
            12345, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am =
            (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
                3000,pendingIntent);

      } catch (Exception e) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      }
```